# Webpack: Shimming external libraries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, lodash

I've been working on webpack configuration in my project and I'm stuck at two specific problems:

1. Including lodash as external library.
2. Specifying dependencies between modules.

**Problem 1**

**Edit:** I've found the answer so I decided to make it more accessible.

I was looking for a way to externalize lodash and had problem with correct configuration of externals in webpack.config.js. Thanks to **Sokra** answer I found in gitter archives: webpack/webpack/archives/2014/11/03 I was able to come up with config like this:

```
    externals: {
      lodash: {
        root: "_",
        commonjs: "lodash",
        commonjs2: "lodash",
        amd: "lodash"
      },
      angular: 'angular'
    }
```

**Edit**

I have moved second part of the problem to the separate post (36596161)

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we try to keep posts about a single issue, consider creating multiple posts. Also, you should have the answer and the question separate

Comment: thanks for the pointers, I'll move second part of the question to a separate post.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).